# Rails giving error when using distinct for removing duplicate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, distinct

I have a controller method in which I am crawling data from different websites. I use distinct in query so that duplicate records should not be displayed.

When I add pagination in my view file it gives some error but without pagination it works fine.

Here is my controller method:

```
def search_results
  @search_data = RtaDubai.where(query_string: @topic.title)
    .distinct(:query_string).page(params[:page]).order('id desc')
end
```

Here is my view file pagination code:

```
<%= will_paginate @search_data %>
```

Here is the error:

> F, [2019-03-06T08:52:03.692939 #106281] FATAL -- : [c72525d9-dcd2-   4e7d-9851-d72f3940ec09] ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError:ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
>
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ) FROM "rta_dubai" WHERE "rta_dubai"."...
>
> : SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ) FROM "rta_dubai" WHERE "rta_dubai"."query_string" = $1):
>
> F, [2019-03-06T08:53:41.989800 #107285] FATAL -- : [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]     94:   <% end %>
>
> [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]     95: 
>
> [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]     96: -->
>
> [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]     97:   <%= will_paginate  @search_data %>
>
> [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]     98: -->
>
> [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]     99: 
>
> [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]    100:
>
> F, [2019-03-06T08:53:41.989829 #107285] FATAL -- : [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]
>
> F, [2019-03-06T08:53:41.989852 #107285] FATAL -- : [3946d2c4-3fa3-486c-aa48-c5454b54d111]
>
> app/views/sentiment_analysis/search_results.html.erb:97:in     `_app_views_sentiment_analysis_search_results_html_erb__418975307880197008
> 2_38946080'

Answer (score 1):

```
def search_results
  params[:page] ||= 1
  @search_data = RtaDubai.where(query_string: @topic.title)
    .uniq
    .order('id desc')
    .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
end
```

Comment: params[:page] ||= 1
where should i put this?

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf just above the query line, you can have a look at updated answer

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf Also don't pass any param in `distinct` please have a look at complete answer on updated answer.

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf Possibly replace `page` to  `paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)` answer updated.

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf Have you replaced page with paginate(..) ?

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf Hmm can you just try it `@search_data = RtaDubai.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)` ?

Comment: with this i will not get any data beacuse we are removing where clause

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf With this you will get all data of that table, with limit of 30. i'm just trying to test it if it's working then will modify this query accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf Glad to know that, also i think `.paginate(...)` will be required to make pagination work. anyway feel free to accept/upvote answer for future SO searchers.